# Debug session was finished without being paused

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, lampp, ubuntu-20.04

In my Laravel project using PhpStorm (2018.1) I am not able to debug my session using xdebug (2.9.5). Any breakpoint gets ignored and session ends without being paused. If I set ***Break at first line in PHP scripts*** then session stops at index.php file. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

```
PHP 7.4.5 (cli) (built: Apr 23 2020 08:10:29) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

This are my settings for xdebug in php.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
```

I have some PhpStorm settings:
[image]

[image]

[image]

What am I missing here?

I also have Xdebug helper extension in my Chromium but it seems to have the same effect with it enabled as well as disabled.

Comment: Try removing the `Servers` entry and unchecking `PHP | Debug | Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations`, on the next debug session, PhpStorm should present you with the Incoming connections dialog and figure out the mappings on its own.

Comment: I did that, many times. **Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations** was always unchecked.

Comment: Xdebug can be tricky in times. Do you access the page through the browser? Does it run directly in your system or do you have a virtual layer like vagrant or Docker?

Comment: @AlexBor 1) Enable and collect Xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug session 2) What file is that (where the breakpoints are)? The full path I mean. 3) Any symbolic links in the path? 4) Is that local or remote/virtual PHP? 5) If you place `xdebug_break();` in your code -- will it stop there?

Comment: It's directly in my system.
Log can be found here:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/P8WTQfcdPV/
xdebug_brake() does nothing.
It's local setup, not remote.
No symbolic links, as far as i know, in the path.

Comment: Try adding a simple assignment statement to the beginning of this file (right under the PHP tag) and set a breakpoint there, would it stop on this breakpoint?

Comment: @AlexBor 1) What is the full path to the file where breakpoint is set? 2) Please show that part of the file where breakpoint is (that line + ~10 lines above & below it). need to see the line numbers as well.

Comment: @LazyOne https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qpfRT5DmRW/

Comment: @AlexBor Sorry, I mean the screenshot of how it looks in the file. The actual code is useless without the context.

Comment: @LazyOne https://pasteboard.co/J8YpPjZ.png

Comment: OK, so I will be guessing again... I ASSUME that the red line is where the breakpoint is set? Line #45 as I understand? Based on what I see from the logs Xdebug resolves that line to be line #50 instead... which I GUESS would be the line with `/* @var int $jurisdictionId */`. It's not PhpStorm, it's Xdebug does not stop... Try disabling this option/if it make any diff `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug | Notify if breakpoint was resolved to a different line (Xdebug 2.8+)`. P.S. `xdebug_break();` should have helped here... no idea why it does not do anything for you.

Comment: Yes, that's the breakpoint. And the line is good, it's 49 and it shows in latest log entry.
I don't see that option:
https://pasteboard.co/J8YxkiY.png

Comment: Try upgrading IDE to the latest 2020.1.1 version then (2018 does not have such option). No better suggestions right now. P.S. Even if you cannot upgrade -- just install it in a separate folder and try if it will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my Laravel project using PhpStorm (2018.1) I am not able to debug my session using xdebug (2.9.5).

It just triggered:

- PhpStorm 2018.1
- Xdebug 2.9.5

You have to upgrade PhpStorm. **You need PhpStorm 2018.3 or newer** in order to be able to work with Xdebug 2.7 or newer.

The problem is in changed XML namespace in Xdebug protocol, as of Xdebug 2.7 (https instead of http). It's fixed/supported since PhpStorm 2018.3 (see [WI-43622](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-43622)).

With your current IDE version you may work with Xdebug 2.6.x max (which does not support PHP 7.4).

Comment: Okay, I will update PhpStorm, keep you posted and thanks.

Comment: Yeap, it works with PhpStorm 2020.1.
Awesome and big thanks.